# How to load and execute query log on mysql server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

Hi i'm new on this site and i thank you all right now for the help you guys are hopefully going to give me. I am also new to the mysql enviroment. So, i have been told by my professor to find some tools which given in input log files (general or slow query) reproduces on a mysql server all the queries such as select, delete, update and insert. The tool should possibly be multi-threaded. I found something like mysql workbench or mk-log-player but i'm not sure if that is what i am looking for since as i have told before i'm new in the mysql enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I think You want Sql client for using Mysql
use SQL-yog client it is good for multiple connections to database.

you can download it from here

http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list